# How to install RabbitMQ on EC2 instance (ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, erlang, ubuntu-16.04

I am facing problem while installing Rabbit MQ on Amazon EC2 instance in Ubuntu-xenial-16.04 environment.
I am following this link to install
 [Install Rabbit MQ](https://tecadmin.net/install-rabbitmq-server-on-ubuntu/)

And when I go to 4th step "sudo apt-get install erlang erlang-nox", seems some problem with dependencies.

[image]

Could anyone help to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i successfully installed rabbit-mq following the guide in their website and using their custom repos on Bintray https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-bintray, but haven't tested it thoughtfully yet.
A TL;DR summary:

1. Add Signing Key
   `wget -O - "https://github.com/rabbitmq/signing-keys/releases/download/2.0/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc" | sudo apt-key add -`
2. Install this
   `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`
3. Add source list: create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list` and edit it something like this:

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list**

```
# This repository provides Erlang packages
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian xenial erlang
# This repository provides RabbitMQ packages
deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial main
```

4. Update and install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install erlang-nox
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

Hope this helps